# Selecting words between square brackets in regex but when there's multiple occurences

Tags: php, regex

I've saved a link to regex101:

https://regex101.com/r/KByCFK/1

I've put in bold what I'm trying to get "I WANT THIS". It automatically goes to the last one. I can see why because of the ".*", but if I make it ungreedy I only get the first letter of the word

I've read the other questions, if it was just a case of getting all the occurrences it wouldn't be a problem

Comment: what words exactly do you want to match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
'''([^\']+)'''((?!is).)*is an? (\[\[[^\[]+\]\]).*
```

https://regex101.com/r/KByCFK/4

Comment: No because it has to be preceded by the name and three apostrophes else "is a" could occur anywhere in the string but not be the definition of the object

Comment: oh i see makes sense, one moment

Comment: I changed my answer please take a look and tell me if this works better

Comment: It is precisely what I'm after, but it doesn't work in my code for some reason, but it works perfectly on the website, so you deserve the tick

Comment: could you show me your code? there might be an issue with it.

Comment: It's because I'm an idiot and wasn't using preg_match_all so it was only returning the space